# Section with h1 and p tags fixed and z-index show overflow

Tags: html, css

Currently use that way when hover on a section name (ex: .test3) use transform: scale(1.1); what is works fine until the mouse goes move from it. Btw it is scale that page and will be hidden the content before. But when the mouse is move out from it then show all in one place (h1 and p with position: fixed;). It is work in up to date browser but like in IE 11 show the h1 and p tags in same place so need to hover in a section first to be readable and only show that section what is on hover. How can fix this? With some z-index options may be? Try a lot of things but nothing. Please help!

CSS:

```
*,*::before,*::after
{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

*
{
    position: relative;
}

a,body,footer,header,h1,h2,html,img,li,p,section,span,sup,ul
{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

.test1:hover,.test2:hover,.test3:hover,.test4:hover,.test5:hover,.test6:hover
{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(10%);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    filter: grayscale(10%);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 1;
}

html
{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 233%;
}

body
{
    background: #FFFFFF 50% 50%/cover no-repeat padding-box border-box fixed;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: normal normal normal 0.938em/175% "Work Sans";
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 233%;
}

section
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.test1,.test2,.test3,.test4,.test5,.test6
{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%);
    -webkit-transition: all 2.5s ease-out 0s;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: grayscale(90%);
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 2.5s ease-out 0s;
    width: 16.66%;
}

h1
{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    bottom: 0;
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40%;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    user-select: none;
    position: fixed;
}

p
{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<section class="test1" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
<ul>
<li><h1>test1</h1>
<li>
<p>test</p>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
<section class="test2" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
<ul>
<li><h1>test2</h1>
<li>
<p>testtest</p>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
<section class="test3" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
<ul>
<li><h1>test3</h1>
<li>
<p>testtesttest</p>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
<section class="test4" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
<ul>
<li><h1>test4</h1>
<li>
<p>testtesttesttest</p>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
<section class="test5" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
<ul>
<li><h1>test5</h1>
<li>
<p>testtesttesttesttest</p>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
<section class="test6" style="background-image: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/cool-background.jpg');">
<ul>
<li><h1>test6</h1>
<li>
<p>testtesttesttesttesttest</p>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Windows 10 with IE11:

[Overflow all six section in same place.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DTZv.jpg)

Any idea?

Comment: I tried editing to fix your English, but I don't understand half of what you're saying

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you are trying to do, but u shouldn't do all that styling and stuff in the body or html tag. A lot of the stuff u did doesn't make any sense at all... read up on some Css and Html stuff it will help for sure. However i tried to get something helpful out of your code. I think u meant that the 
text on hover is all on the same place etc. You have used fixed position on the text, that wont work and place all the text on exactly the same position,i changed it to relative and fixed some other stuff

Update:

i think i understood what u meant, u want to show the text only on hovering

Updated show on hover :

https://jsfiddle.net/1t4ch8Lb/8/

```
.test1,
.test2,
.test3,
.test4,
.test5,
.test6 {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%);
  -webkit-transition: all 2.5s ease-out 0s;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(90%);
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 2.5s ease-out 0s;
  width: 16.66%;
}

.test1:hover,
.test2:hover,
.test3:hover,
.test4:hover,
.test5:hover,
.test6:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(10%);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  filter: grayscale(10%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  display: block;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  // display: none;
}

section:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I mean show the h1 and p tags with fixed position side by side. That is possible? I try your code it is work btw no need to hide the ul element.

Comment: i updated the code, but what do u mean by fixed? they are now fixed realtive to its container, if u would make them position absolute they would stay always on the exact position even if u have content below and scroll down ..the lements will be always visible on the fixed position.